# Creating dictionaries to connect words to numbers

Tags: python, dictionary, paramiko

I am writing a script that works for one device (doing automation). 
For example I have a device, with an IP so currently i had my code setup with a variable. `ip1 = 127.0.0.1`.

But now I want to be able to touch approx 100 devices, so I want to create a file or best recommendation to have for example:

```
Device 1 127.0.0.1
Device 2 127.0.0.2
```

Once a call is made for either or, the code executes. I think the best way is to create a "dictionary file" Could someone point me in the right direction in order to do so? Or would I be creating a CSV file with two columns? What is the best recommend method? Someone seemed to have told me to create a dictionary file, but I am unsure what that entails.

My code is currently something along the lines of

```
ip1 = "127.0.0.0.1"

username = "username"
password = "password"

print("\nHello, user You are connecting to ", ip, "\n")

ssh_conn = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_conn.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_conn.connect(ip, port=22, username=username,
                     password=password,
                     look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
```

So just to clarify again, I am looking to replace `ip1 =` with a file that would store almost 10-100 IP addresses and based on the "Name of the device" it would execute the code.

I know an example is as follows:

```
released = {
    "iphone": 2007,
    "iphone 3G": 2008,
    "iphone 3GS": 2009,
    "iphone 4": 2010,
    "iphone 4S": 2011,
    "iphone 5": 2012
}

for item in released:
    if "iphone 5" in released:
        print("Key found")
        break
    else:
        print("No keys found")
```

But what do I do if I am going to be adding 100 key values?

**EDIT**

I go this idea,

```
with open('inventory.txt', 'r') as f:
    answer = {}
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        if not line:
            continue
        answer[line[0]] = line[1:]

id = "1299"
for i in answer[store_num]:
    host = i
    ssh = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios', host=host, username='asd', password='asdsssasd')
    print("\nConnection successful with: ", host, "\n")
    out = ssh.send_command(command)
    print(out)
```

But I am getting an error connecting to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using this in order to use a text file instead of CSV.

```
with open('inventory.txt', 'r') as f:
    answer = {}
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        if not line:
            continue
        answer[line[0]] = line[1:]

data_number = input("INFO: Enter Device Number: ")
for i in answer[data_number]:
    host = i
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `CSV` file to store all the IPs and their corresponding host names like,

```
Device 1,127.0.0.1
Device 2,127.0.0.2
```

Then you can use the pythons built in `csv` module to read those data into a dictionary, like

```
import csv

info = {}
with open("master.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for item in reader:
        info[item[0]] = item[1]
```

Then you could ask the user, which device name to connect?

```
device = input("Device name: ")
ip = info.get(device, None) #--> get the ip address from the info dict
```

If the IP is not `None`, then you will be able to connect the user.

Comment: When trying your method I get "line 16, in <module>
    info[item[0]] = item[1]
IndexError: list index out of range" am I supposed to put Device 1,127.0.0.1
 in one column?

Comment: @AlehandroTheGreat If you are planning to use `csv` file then just write `DeviceName,IP` per line of the file.

Comment: using the CSV method I put Device 1,127.1.0.0.1 ,Device 2,127.0.1.1.1 into Column A.  added `import csv

info = {}
with open("master.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for item in reader:
        info[item[0]] = item[1]`

Using `device = input("Device name: ")
ip = info.get(device, None) #--> get the ip address from the info dict` 

I am now getting line 16, in <module>
    info[item[0]] = item[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

**line 16 is:         info[item[0]] = item[1]**

Comment: @AlehandroTheGreat If you are preparing the csv file using some spreadsheet program then you have to put `DeviceName` in one column and `IP` in another column.

Comment: I up voted your answer, because it was helpful but I ended up not using a CSV file. Thank you though!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am quoting from your question:

> Someone seemed to have told me to create a dictionary file, but I am unsure what that entails.

[see this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

in your scenario it would like this:

```py
ip_adresses = {
  "Device 1": "127.0.0.1",
  "Device 2": "127.0.0.2"
}
```

then you would run it like this:

```py
for device, ip in ip_adresses.items():
    print("This is " + device + ". IP Address: " + ip)
```

Final Code:

```
device_you_are_using = "Device 2"

ip_addresses = {
  "Device 1": "127.0.0.1",
  "Device 2": "127.0.0.2"
}

for device, ip in ip_addresses.items():
    if device_you_are_using == device:
        print("This is " + device + ". IP Address: " + ip)
```

Comment: so you would add a big list to your main,py file with 100 + lines of a dictionary?

Comment: @Alehandro it does not have be in the main file. It can be in another file that just contains the list and you import it.